# Закрыть Activity при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android

Есть пример кода, в котором создается уведомление и кнопка. И по нажатию на кнопку в уведомлении открывается Activity.

А как сделать, чтобы наоборот при нажатии на кнопку активити закрывалось и само уведомление исчезало?

```
public void sendActionNotification(View view) {
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Намерение для запуска второй активности
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// Строим уведомление
Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setTicker("Пришла посылка!")
        .setContentTitle("Посылка")
        .setContentText(
                "Это я, почтальон Печкин. Принес для вас посылку")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Открыть", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Отказаться", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Другой вариант", pIntent)
        .build();

// убираем уведомление, когда его выбрали
builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, builder);
}
```

stack trace:

```
E/ActivityThread: Activity ru.mysite.Player has leaked IntentReceiver ru.mysite.Player$1@45b817e that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity ru.mysite.Player has leaked IntentReceiver ru.mysite.Player$1@45b817e that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1159)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:946)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1330)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1310)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1304)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:586)
    at ru.mysite.Player.onCreate(Player.java:152)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Intent maybeReceive = new Intent();  
 maybeReceive.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
 PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, maybeReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 // Строим уведомление
 Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
     .setTicker("Пришла посылка!")
     .setContentTitle("Играет: " + котенок)
     .setContentText("Это я, почтальон Печкин. Принес для вас посылку")
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_play).setContentIntent(pIntent)
     .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "ОК", pendingIntentMaybe)
     .build();

// убираем уведомление, когда его выбрали
builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, builder);
```

В вашем активити в `onCreate()`

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      // действия при получении сообщений
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
      }
    };
// создаем фильтр для BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
// регистрируем (включаем) BroadcastReceiver
registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
```

MAYBE_ACTION - любая уникальная для приложения строка

Comment: А можете сказать что тут именно происходит maybeReceive.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
 PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, maybeReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); и как связывается BroadcastReceiver с кнопкой?

Comment: Когда нажимаю в уведомлении кнопку Стоп, то в логе выводится ошибка. Свой вопрос обновил.

Comment: Когда вы нажимаете на кнопку, то отсылается сообщение с action MAYBE_ACTION. BroadcastReceiver может перехватывать сообщения на которые он подписан. Соответственно ваш BroadcastReceiver подписан на MAYBE_ACTION, он и поймает сообщение. а ошибка потому что нужно сделать unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceive); на onDestroy

Comment: Спасибо. Понял.